# Can we reprocess group licenses via PowerShell when migrating from direct licensing to group licensing?

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm about to transition from direct licensing in Office 365 to group-based licensing, which will also involve changing to a difference license for many users.  The new license has a conflicting service plan with the old (direct) one.

In testing we found that if we apply the group prior to removing the direct license, the user gets a licensing error.  When the direct license is then removed, the user must be reprocessed in order to get the group-based license.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-groups-resolve-problems#how-do-you-force-license-processing-in-a-group-to-resolve-errors

I have not been able to figure out a way to reprocess the user's license via PowerShell.  Am I overlooking something, or is that feature only available via the web UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the license reprocessing was flawed.  I thought users had to be reprocessed individually, which is not the case.  Reprocessing handles the entire group at once, so there was no need to code anything for reprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can finally use the following code to get all group with license name after completing the steps in the following link:

```
PS C:\PowershellQuery> & '.\ group-list-with-license-assgined.ps1'
```

For more information, please review the following link:

[Get licenses applied to groups in new Azure AD using PowerShell](https://www.jijitechnologies.com/blogs/how-to-list-out-all-groups-with-all-applied-license-using-powershell)

Also you can review the following link for reference:

[Group licensing with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-ps-examples)